# Can't access parameter value in Angular app

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular and am trying to understand how to access the id value in Urls such as /page/34 and /page/65 in my basic angular app. I created a new app and also a component "PageComponent". Here is my code:

```
//app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageComponent } from './page/page.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'page/:id', component: PageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

//page.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.css']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
    });
  }

}
```

I test the app with "ng serve" and open a page like http://localhost:4200/page/878. But in the console all I see is {}. I.e., it seems the params array is empty.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: did you add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your root component html (i.e. app.component.html)?

Comment: @lancovici - that has fixed it. Thanks so much. I hadn't added that. If you want to write it as an answer I can accept that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add router-outlet in your root component when using routes in your angular app root component (i.e. `app.component.ts`)

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```